# Language preferable for designing desktop widgets

Tags: java, gui, widget

I was trying to make a desktop widget as a small project (something like clock). I was initially using Java, but was not able to find a way to disable drag property of JFrame. (Don't want user to move it). I tried to search but only found that it is not possible in Java GUI.
Which language should I use that allows me to disable the drag feature of Main Frame Window. If it is possible in Java, then how can I do that?
Recommend for both Windows and Linux OS.

Answer (score 1):

## Xojo

[Xojo](http://www.Xojo.com/) is a powerful yet easy-to-use software development toolset for building cross-platform apps. For desktop apps you can deploy across Mac, Windows, and Linux.

The *Global Floating Window* appears to be the kind of window frame you seek. See [this section of the User Guide](http://developer.xojo.com/userguide/desktop-windows).